# Display the total number of rows in a Slickgrid table

Tags: slickgrid

Is there an accepted way to display the total number of rows in a slickgrid table. I see that there is a pager that I can include on my pages, but that comes with additional buttons/settings for pagination.

I am using a DataView object with no grouping. Ideally I'd like to simply have a trivial row at the bottom of the viewport that lists how many rows are in the table.

I could do this manually but wasn't sure if I was missing something in the Slickgrid APIs/configuration.

Comment: Hi, any chance to share some snippet if you managed to do this. I modified slickgrid.remotemodel and it works, but I'm stuck with how to use dataview on this.

Comment: I can't share my code but I can describe what I did. When the data changes I would manually recalculate all the totals by iterating through my dataset. I would then add the "Totals" row to my new dataset, and then do something like dataView.setItems(newDataWithTotalsAdded); grid.invalidate();grid.render()

Comment: thank you very much. Oh, I got it. I thought you didn't add a row on the bottom of table. I'm trying to make dataView subscribe onRowCountChanged() function so it would automatically render a text like "total rows: 2324".

Comment: To display the totals outside of the table, I did exactly what you're describing: dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) { ...}. I ended up creating a slickgrid pager that gets added to the page when the grid is created: var pager = Slick.Controls.MyCustomPager(dataView, grid, $('#pager')); You can read the source to understand how to make a custom pager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this method...to get number of rows displayed in the grid..(if no pagination is there)

```
grid.getDataLength();
```

if pagination is there....use this..

```
grid.getData().getPagingInfo().pageNum
grid.getData().getPagingInfo().pageSize
grid.getData().getPagingInfo().totalPages
grid.getData().getPagingInfo().totalRows   //  what u want
```

Comment: If you have groups, you probably also want to subtract the rows in collapsed groups from `totalRows`

Answer (score 0):

Use the onRowCountChanged for dataView argument in Slick Grid.

```
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e,args)
{
   $("#RowCount").text(args.current);
});
```