# SlickGrid: Get the total no of rows after Grouping

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am grouping the slickgrid table, and I want to know the no.of rows after grouping.

> I found this solution
>     **`grid.getData().getPagingInfo().totalRows`**
>   from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16992444/3876896).

But it is not working for the table after grouping. 
It returns the total no.of rows of the `data` not the updated no.of rows after grouping.
Please help me to solve this

Comment: Not sure if this is how it works when using grouping, but the `view` typically has the count of what is visible.

Comment: @Prem did you check my asnwer if it was correct?

Comment: @kayess no it didn't worked, any how i found some other way to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question right, but to me it seems that you are confusing Slick objects here. The `grid.getData()` will return the complete datasource of your grid.

If you take a look at the official SlickGrid [example-grouping](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping) demo, you will see a grid with grouped set of datas. You can try yourself by opening your favorite browsers Javascript debugger:

```
dataView.getGroups()
```

It will return you the corresponding `Array` of objects from the [`dataview`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) that contains all groups informations like:

> Array [ Object, Object, ... , another 15... ]

You can reach these objects thru specifying the given element key of the returned array:

```
dataView.getGroups()[0]
```

Return value of command:

> Object {__group: true, level: 0, count: 1, value: 0, title:
>   "Duration:  0  1, groups: null, groupingKey: "0"}

Now we can see that it has a `count` property which contains the exact number of rows belong to that group.

So finally by issuing:

```
dataView.getGroups()[0].count
```

Will return you:

> 1

Or by issuing:

```
dataView.getGroups()[1].count
```

Will return you:

> 3

Where both returned `count` numbers equal with the record numbers you can see in the grid.